# Slideshow with lock on Raspberry PI

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, pam

G'day,

I'm using `PAMUSB` to lock my RPi, which works fine. When the USB Stick is pulled, I use `xscreensaver-command -lock` to lock the machine.
Here comes the tricky part, I can't quite figure out yet. xscreensaver comes with several slideshows, but pretty much all of them suck because they insist on useless transition effects. Also I can't use any GLX modules ( e.g. GLSlideshow ) which would do exactly as I want.

I tried to compile `xv` on the pi with little luck. I now got `pqiv` working, but I'm struggling to make it mate with `xscreensaver`.

What I did last was make an entry in ~/.xscreensaver under `programs:` like `"PQIV slideshow"  pqiv -ifst -d 5 /media/03A1-13EE/                 \n\` but it does not start the slideshow. The command works flawless when started from the command line.

Any help would be fantastic! I'd also love a different approach, but it has to lock the PI! (i'm using a multitouch display with it )

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got XV compiled:

Get souce from: www.trilon.com/xv/downloads.html

```
tar -xzf xv-3.10a.tar.gz
cd xv-3.10a
sudo nano tiff/RANLIB.csh
```

comment out every line but one so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
#
# tests to see if the program 'ranlib' exists.  If it does, runs ranlib on
# the first argument (a library name).  Otherwise, does nothing, and returns
#
# written by John Bradley for the XV 3.00 release
# thanks to John Hagan for shell-script hackery
#

#echo "executing 'ranlib $1'..."

# Is there a ranlib?  Let's try and then suffer the consequences...
ranlib $1 >& /dev/null
#
#if ( $status ) then 
#   echo "There doesn't seem to be a ranlib on this system..."
#   echo "Don't worry about it."
#endif

#echo ""
#echo ""

sudo nano xv.h
```

change:

```
extern char *sys_errlist[];     /* this too... */
```

to

```
/*     extern char *sys_errlist[];     /* this too... */


sudo make
sudo make install
```

Still throws some warnings, but works like a charm with `PAM` and `XSCREENSAVER`

The entry in `~/.xscreensaver` under `programs:` looks like this:

```
default-n:          xv -root -rmode 5 -random -viewonly       \
                  -wloop -wait 5 /some/folder/*.JPG     \n\
```

Hope that helps anyone!

Cheers!